# Users are not saving in ManyToMany Field drf

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am learning django rest framework and I have a field named `users` in my `Blog` Model with **ManyToManyField** to **User** and I am trying to save multiple users in `.post()` request.

models.py

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="users")
```

views.py

```
class BlogCreateView(mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                        GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = BlogSerializer
    queryset = Blog.objects.all()

    def post(self, request, pk, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as e:
            return Response({"error": "something went wrong"},)
```

serializers.py

```
class BlogSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    users = serializers.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = Blog
        fields = "__all__"

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user_usernames = validated_data.pop('users', [])
        blog = Blog.objects.create(**validated_data)
        users = User.objects.filter(username__in=user_usernames)
        blog.users.set(users)
        return blog
```

It is not saving when I pass user names string like "user1", "user2".

Then I thought maybe passing username string may be antipattern then I tried to convert CharField into ListField like

```
    users = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.CharField())
```

but then it showed

> {
> "error": "'ManyRelatedManager' object is not iterable"
> }

Answer (score 1):

At first, modify the `users` field as a `ListField` with a child `CharField`, so that you can pass a list of usernames as input.

Additionally, use `to_representation()` method to return a list of usernames instead of a `ManyRelatedManager` object so:

```py
class BlogSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    users = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.CharField())

    class Meta:
        model = Blog
        fields = "__all__"

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user_usernames = validated_data.pop('users', [])
        blog = Blog.objects.create(**validated_data)
        users = User.objects.filter(username__in=user_usernames)
        blog.users.set(users)
        return blog

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        ret = super().to_representation(instance)
        ret['users'] = list(instance.users.all().values_list('username', flat=True))
        return ret
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer,  It is still showing `ManyRelatedManager' object is not iterable`

Comment: @Proco Can you share the full traceback by editing the question?

Comment: It is showing this error when I call API in response and in console it is just showing `Bad Request: /blog/create/`

Comment: Showing {
  "error": "Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use users.set() instead."
}

Comment: Still same error {
  "error": "'ManyRelatedManager' object is not iterable"
}

Comment: @Proco which line gives this error, can you share full traceback?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252190/discussion-between-sunderam-dubey-and-proco).